# What is the code for Autocomplete in a ComboBox Using C# and Access 2017?

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, autocomplete

I want to make Autocomplete in a ComboBox Using C# and Access 2017.So I used this code... But i can not understand what the mean of "&lt"and "&gt". There are some errors with these places. Please help me to fix this error.

```
private void Autocomplete()
    {
        string query; 
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Neth1.accdb");
        //opening connection
        con.Open();
        try
       {
        //initialize a new instance of sqlcommand
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        //set a connection used by this instance of sqlcommand
         cmd.Connection = con;
         //set the sql statement to execute at the data source
         cmd.CommandText = query;

          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
         //set the sql statement or stored procedure to execute at the data source
         da.SelectCommand = cmd;
         //initialize a new instance of DataTable
         DataTable dt=new DataTable ();
         //add or resfresh rows in the certain range in the datatable to match those in the data source.
         da.Fill(dt);


         foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
         {
         //getting all rows in the specific field|Column
         var rw = r.Field &lt; string &gt;("IMEI");

         //Set the properties of a combobox to make it auto suggest.
         comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
         comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
         //adding all rows into the combobox
         comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(rw);

         }
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
          //catching error 
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         //release all resources used by the component
         da.Dispose(); 
         //clossing connection
         con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` = less than

`&gt;` = greater than

```
var rw = r.Field &lt; string &gt;("IMEI");
```

becomes

```
var rw = r.Field<string>("IMEI");
```